# mysql - why condition where is not work?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
    t1.user_id,
    count(*) total,
    sum(case when t1.var1 = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end) as type1,
    sum(case when t1.var1 = 'no' then 1 else 0 end) as type2
FROM table as t1
WHERE type1 > 0
GROUP by t1.user_id
ORDER by type1 DESC
LIMIT 100
```

In result i get rows:

```
user_id  total  type1  type2
  1       100    80     20
  4       120    70     50
  6       90     0      90
```

Tell me please why condition `WHERE type1 > 0` not work and how select rows with this condition ?

Comment: make an sql fiddle for these questions, it makes it easier for us to try stuff: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: ...and show the original tables (and their data) you are querying from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WHERE` only works on the original value and not on a variable you just made by summing the other values up, you can use `HAVING` for this:

```
SELECT
t1.user_id,
count(*) total,
sum(case when t1.var1 = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end) as type1,
sum(case when t1.var1 = 'no' then 1 else 0 end) as type2
FROM table as t1
GROUP by t1.user_id
HAVING type1 > 0
ORDER by type1 DESC
LIMIT 100
```

See here for another example of using `HAVING`: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Comment: No problem :) Don't forget to mark an answer so your question doesn't show up as unsolved, but only if you have no more questions about this, otherwise i'd be happy to answer any further questions about this ^^